# Why won't `tail -f` follow my syslog when running live?

Tags: command-line, live-environment, tail

I want to monitor `/var/log/syslog` for any changes in realtime (or within-a-few-seconds-of-time), but `tail -f` won't update with any new changes.

I'm running Ubuntu-based Linux Mint 17 XFCE live now, but this hasn't worked on live iso's of Ubuntu, Xubuntu, or Linux Mint Mate either.

I've tried these:

`$ tail -f /var/log/syslog`
`$ tail -f --retry -s 1 /var/log/syslog`
`$ tail --follow=name  /var/log/syslog`
`$ tail --follow=name --retry  /var/log/syslog`
`$ tail --follow=name --retry -s 1 /var/log/syslog`

But it only initially outputs the last few lines of the file, then no updates when the file grows (when, for example, trying to mount an empty file gives about 15 lines of errors).

Actually, even trying to follow a test file in my home folder doesn't seem to work, running `tail -f testfile` and then (in another terminal):
`$ echo "new stuff" >> testfile`
`$ echo "new stuff2" >> testfile`
`$ echo "3" >> testfile`
doesn't result in any updates to `tail` either...
But if I put `testfile` in `/tmp`(mounted on a tmpfs) then it *does* follow the file's changes.

### **Why won't tail follow?**

Is there something weird about running live, or overlayfs that cripples `tail -f`? And any suggestions how to follow the log? (`xwatch` works ok, anything better or in terminal?)

---

I've tried running `strace tail -f  -s 1 testfile` and here are the last couple lines of output, after it `write(1,`'s the existing couple lines of `testfile`:

```
write(1, "new1\n", 5new1
)                   = 5
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22, ...}) = 0
fstatfs64(3, 84, {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=968776, f_bfree=461437, f_bavail=461437, f_files=203469, f_ffree=190635, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=1056}) = 0
inotify_init()                          = 4
inotify_add_watch(4, "testfile", IN_MODIFY|IN_ATTRIB|IN_DELETE_SELF|IN_MOVE_SELF) = 1
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22, ...}) = 0
read(4,
```

Comment: How long do you wait before declaring a failure? Have you read `man tail`? The `--sleep-interval=N` parameter might help. Or you could `strace tail -f /var/log/syslog` and see where `tail` is waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll try `strace` asap. I did check `man tail`, and the `-s` in my trials is an alias for `--sleep-interval`. Not at all sure how to interpret the `strace` results, but I'll paste the last few lines after it prints the existing file contents, last line is a `read(4,`. Beginning to think it is a bug, or just incompatible with overlayfs. I wait a few minutes after an `echo new >> testfile`, nothing happens

Comment: `tail` uses `inotify` to watch the files. Does `inotify` work with `overlayfs`? It seems not to. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/882147 (sorry about doubled comment - while I was finding out about tail, inotify and overlayfs, my earlier comment timed out). Also see http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/overlayfs-inotify--ftopict551004.html

Comment: @waltinator it does not :) (and you can remove comments ;) )

Comment: @waltinator I just found that first bug too, from searching "Does inotify work with overlayfs". And the "undocumented" `tail` workaround `---disable-inotify` that makes `tail` work "like it used to" (apparently it started ignoring `--sleep-interval` around 2010 (linked from the first bug report). If you added the `tail ---disable-inotify`... (from [comment 30](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/882147/comments/30)) that would be a perfect answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tail` uses `inotify` which does not work with `overlayfs` See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/882147) and [this discussion](http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/overlayfs-inotify--ftopict551004.html). @Xen2050 pointed out the `---disable-inotify` switch to `tail` See [this workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/882147/comments/30)

You could use `apt-src` to install the `coreutils` source, and recompile `tail` with `-UHAVE_INOTIFY`