# CUPS save documents sent to printer in hard drive

Tags: printing

I am working on a project where I use Raspberry Pi as a print server. I need to save every document that is sent to the printer in hard drive that is attached to the Raspberry Pi. Can anyone suggest a method to do this?

Comment: Raspberry pi is a Ubuntu flavor? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Read `man inotify`, which begins with:

```
NAME

   inotify - monitoring filesystem events

DESCRIPTION

   The  inotify API provides a mechanism for monitoring filesystem events.
   Inotify can  be  used  to  monitor  individual  files,  or  to  monitor
   directories.  When a directory is monitored, inotify will return events
   for the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.
```

Use it to monitor `/var/spool/cups`. The `/var/spool/cups/c#####` are "control" files, and `/var/spool/cups/d#####-001` files are the actual data to be sent to the printer.

Note: At one time `inotify` did not work on all filesystem types, see [Why won't `tail -f` follow my syslog when running live?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563982/why-wont-tail-f-follow-my-syslog-when-running-live/576592#576592)